# "In" versus "nel" in una frase particolare

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, articles

Qual è la forma corretta?

- Mi piace molto leggere *in* treno prima di cominciare a lavorare.
- Mi piace molto leggere *nel* treno prima di cominciare a lavorare.

Questa frase andrebbe in un testo nel quale ho spiegato in precedenza che ogni mattina prendo un treno locale per andare al lavoro.

Comment: Tra le due, sicuramente la prima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si usa *in* se si vuole parlare del mezzo di trasporto in generale.

> Mi piace leggere **in** treno.
>
> Non mi piace leggere **in** macchina.

Si usa *nel* quando si fa riferimento ad una situazione o ad un certo tipo di mezzo di trasporto, di solito attraverso un complemento di specificazione o un aggettivo. Questa situazione può essere molto generica

> Mi piace leggere **nei** treni Eurostar.

o più specifica

> Mi piace leggere **nel** treno *che prendo per andare al lavoro*.

Se si fa riferimento ad una situazione descritta indipendentemente dal mezzo di trasporto (ad es. con un complemento di tempo), allora si ritorna nel caso precedente.

> Mi piace leggere **in** treno *quando vado al lavoro*.

Answer (score 4):

Devi usare 'in' perché ha la necessaria genericità che 'nel' non ha.

Se usi 'nel' sembra come se ti stessi riferendo a un particolare treno, magari anche fermo in un deposito ferroviario,  e non al treno in senso astratto, cioè inteso quale forma modale di trasporto—che, invece, è quanto tu vuoi intendere.

Answer (score 3):

Davanti a tutti i ***mezzi di trasporto***, tipo *treno, macchina, aereo, e così via*, si usa la preposizione semplice 'in'.

ad esempio:

> Sono andato in macchina a Roma.
>
> Mi piace leggere in treno.

Nota bene: Quando c'è una modificazione al nome con un altro preposizione o aggettivo, come nei seguenti esempi si cambia alla preposizione articolata:

> Mi piace leggere nella macchina di Pietro.
>
> Non posso dormire nel treno affollato.